# Multiple MPMoviePlayerControllers and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Im trying to display multiple MPMoviePlayerController views within a uiscrollview. My app displays a gallery style player for movies, the same as the Photos app. Having read the documentation I understand only one video can play at once, which is fine. Unfortunately, Im seeing that even the controls are not displayed - so I cant stop one movie and play another. Has anyone found a way around this?

The documentation states 'Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time may play its movie.', so I believe it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar recently - my solution was to create an image view showing an image that acted as a placeholder for the movie. When the user tapped the image, I created a new movieplayer instance and replaced the image view with it. If the user tapped a different image view, then I would pause the currently playing movie, remove the player and create a new movie player in the section that was tapped.

I wasn't showing any controls before the movie played, and once the movie was stopped, the controls were removed from the interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion. I'm going to keep looking out for a better solution, but its the best workaround I can see at the moment. Cheers